# App center: build failed - could not find gradleWrapperMain

Tags: android, gradle, wrapper, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to run my app in appcenter, but everytime i try i always get this error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

**What i have tried so far:**

- Removed gradle-wrapper.properties / .jar and ran `gradle wrapper` in the cmd
- Made sure gradlew was added when i ran git commit
- Made sure there is no global gitignore. (or any gitignore who doesnt commit the gradle-wrapper files)

I am out of options. How do i run the application in app center?

Comment: Can you share repro steps? Hard to tell what is wrong at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my problem was that i had multiple gradle files. 
Appcenter was then refering to the wrong gradlewrapper. 
So the fix is -> delete unnecessary gradles

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: Answer to the issue i had